# Unicode error being thrown when trying to make rosserial module

Tags: python, unicode, lisp, ros

I've recently started a project in using ROS to publish events using an arduino from the rosserial module. Whenever I invoke catkin_make on the workspace I make it through many of the packages in rosserial, but get errors when trying to make TopicInfo.msg, Log.msg, and rosserial_arduino. Below is the thrown errors and the problems which are referencing unicode hashing problems. I've tried repathing and sourcing to the correct areas but nothing seems to help. Anyone have suggestions? Also I'm running Arch linux with ROS Hypdro.

```
Generating Lisp code from rosserial_msgs/TopicInfo.msg
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "/opt/ros/hydro/share/gencpp/cmake/../../../lib/gencpp/gen_cpp.py", line 41, in    <module>
    import genmsg.template_tools
 File "/opt/ros/hydro/lib/python2.7/site-packages/genmsg/template_tools.py", line 74
    raise RuntimeError, "Template file %s not found in template dir %s" % (template_file_name, template_dir)
                      ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
    rosserial/rosserial_msgs/CMakeFiles/rosserial_msgs_generate_messages_cpp.dir/build.make:59: recipe for target '/home/jared/Documents/AdvancedRoboticsArm/catkin_ws/devel/include/rosserial_msgs/TopicInfo.h' failed
make[2]: *** [/home/jared/Documents/AdvancedRoboticsArm/catkin_ws/devel/include/rosserial_msgs/TopicInfo.h] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:337: recipe for target 'rosserial/rosserial_msgs/CMakeFiles/rosserial_msgs_generate_messages_cpp.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [rosserial/rosserial_msgs/CMakeFiles/rosserial_msgs_generate_messages_cpp.dir/all] Error 2
make[1]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
[ 20%] Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/ros/hydro/lib/python2.7/site-packages/genlisp/genlisp_main.py", line 71, in genmain
    retcode = generate_msg(options.package, args[1:], options.outdir, search_path)
Generating Lisp code from rosserial_msgs/Log.msg
  File "/opt/ros/hydro/lib/python2.7/site-packages/genlisp/generate.py", line 720, in generate_msg
    generate_msg_from_spec(msg_context, spec, search_path, out_dir, pkg)
  File "/opt/ros/hydro/lib/python2.7/site-packages/genlisp/generate.py", line 770, in generate_msg_from_spec
    write_md5sum(s, msg_context, spec)
  File "/opt/ros/hydro/lib/python2.7/site-packages/genlisp/generate.py", line 591, in write_md5sum
    md5sum = genmsg.compute_md5(msg_context, parent or spec)
  File "/opt/ros/hydro/lib/python2.7/site-packages/genmsg/gentools.py", line 119, in compute_md5
    return _compute_hash(msg_context, spec, hashlib.md5())
  File "/opt/ros/hydro/lib/python2.7/site-packages/genmsg/gentools.py", line 103, in _compute_hash
    hash.update(compute_md5_text(msg_context, spec))
TypeError: Unicode-objects must be encoded before hashing
ERROR:  Unicode-objects must be encoded before hashing
rosserial/rosserial_msgs/CMakeFiles/rosserial_msgs_generate_messages_lisp.dir/build.make:58: recipe for target '/home/jared/Documents/AdvancedRoboticsArm/catkin_ws/devel/share/common-lisp/ros/rosserial_msgs/msg/TopicInfo.lisp' failed
make[2]: *** [/home/jared/Documents/AdvancedRoboticsArm/catkin_ws/devel/share/common-lisp/ros/rosserial_msgs/msg/TopicInfo.lisp] Error 3
make[2]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
[ 25%] Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/ros/hydro/lib/python2.7/site-packages/genpy/generator.py", line 965, in generate_messages
    outfile = self.generate(msg_context, full_type, f, outdir, search_path) #actual generation
  File "/opt/ros/hydro/lib/python2.7/site-packages/genpy/generator.py", line 946, in generate
    for l in self.generator_fn(msg_context, spec, search_path):
  File "/opt/ros/hydro/lib/python2.7/site-packages/genpy/generator.py", line 885, in srv_generator
    for l in msg_generator(msg_context, mspec, search_path):
  File "/opt/ros/hydro/lib/python2.7/site-packages/genpy/generator.py", line 736, in msg_generator
    md5sum = genmsg.compute_md5(msg_context, spec)
  File "/opt/ros/hydro/lib/python2.7/site-packages/genmsg/gentools.py", line 119, in compute_md5
    return _compute_hash(msg_context, spec, hashlib.md5())
  File "/opt/ros/hydro/lib/python2.7/site-packages/genmsg/gentools.py", line 103, in _compute_hash
    hash.update(compute_md5_text(msg_context, spec))
TypeError: Unicode-objects must be encoded before hashing

ERROR: Unable to generate services for package 'rosserial_msgs': while processing '/home/jared/Documents/AdvancedRoboticsArm/catkin_ws/src/rosserial/rosserial_msgs/srv/RequestParam.srv': Unicode-objects must be encoded before hashing

Generating Python srv __init__.py for rosserial_arduino
rosserial/rosserial_msgs/CMakeFiles/rosserial_msgs_generate_messages_py.dir/build.make:78: recipe for target '/home/jared/Documents/AdvancedRoboticsArm/catkin_ws/devel/lib/python3.4/site-packages/rosserial_msgs/srv/_RequestParam.py' failed
make[2]: *** [/home/jared/Documents/AdvancedRoboticsArm/catkin_ws/devel/lib/python3.4/site-packages/rosserial_msgs/srv/_RequestParam.py] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:399: recipe for target 'rosserial/rosserial_msgs/CMakeFiles/rosserial_msgs_generate_messages_py.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [rosserial/rosserial_msgs/CMakeFiles/rosserial_msgs_generate_messages_py.dir/all] Error 2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/ros/hydro/lib/python2.7/site-packages/genlisp/genlisp_main.py", line 71, in genmain
    retcode = generate_msg(options.package, args[1:], options.outdir, search_path)
  File "/opt/ros/hydro/lib/python2.7/site-packages/genlisp/generate.py", line 720, in generate_msg
    generate_msg_from_spec(msg_context, spec, search_path, out_dir, pkg)
  File "/opt/ros/hydro/lib/python2.7/site-packages/genlisp/generate.py", line 770, in generate_msg_from_spec
    write_md5sum(s, msg_context, spec)
  File "/opt/ros/hydro/lib/python2.7/site-packages/genlisp/generate.py", line 591, in write_md5sum
    md5sum = genmsg.compute_md5(msg_context, parent or spec)
  File "/opt/ros/hydro/lib/python2.7/site-packages/genmsg/gentools.py", line 119, in compute_md5
    return _compute_hash(msg_context, spec, hashlib.md5())
  File "/opt/ros/hydro/lib/python2.7/site-packages/genmsg/gentools.py", line 103, in _compute_hash
    hash.update(compute_md5_text(msg_context, spec))
TypeError: Unicode-objects must be encoded before hashing
ERROR:  Unicode-objects must be encoded before hashing
rosserial/rosserial_msgs/CMakeFiles/rosserial_msgs_generate_messages_lisp.dir/build.make:64: recipe for target '/home/jared/Documents/AdvancedRoboticsArm/catkin_ws/devel/share/common-lisp/ros/rosserial_msgs/msg/Log.lisp' failed
make[2]: *** [/home/jared/Documents/AdvancedRoboticsArm/catkin_ws/devel/share/common-lisp/ros/rosserial_msgs/msg/Log.lisp] Error 3
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:368: recipe for target 'rosserial/rosserial_msgs/CMakeFiles/rosserial_msgs_generate_messages_lisp.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [rosserial/rosserial_msgs/CMakeFiles/rosserial_msgs_generate_messages_lisp.dir/all] Error 2
[ 33%] Built target rosserial_arduino_generate_messages_py
Makefile:126: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
Invoking "make" failed
```

Any input would be helpful. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your SyntaxError Exception for the comma in `raise RuntimeError, ...` suggests the Python interpreter is actually Python 3 despite your lib path contains Python 2.7 libs.

Double check your paths and ensure you're running Python 2.7